# How to emulate override of parts of "virtual variadic functions"?

Tags: c++, variadic-templates, virtual-inheritance

First of all, I know that variadic functions can't be virtual in c++. My question is how to emulate the next "incorrect" example. I want to have a class A with "virtual variadic function" and class B which inherits it and implements only "part of it":

```
class A {
template<class... Types>
virtual void f(Types... buffers) { return; }
};

class B : public A {
// Overrides only 2 options of "generic" f
void f(unsigned char* buff2) override;
void f(unsigned char* buff1, unsigned int* buff2) override;
};
```

In my use case it is very important to have this generic `f` call but different classes only support "subsets" of variadic function `f`:

```
A* a= factory(...);
a->f(buff1, buff2, buff3); // OK
a->f(buff1); // OK
a->f(buff1, buff2); // Error! Factory gave an instance which does not support this call
```

Comment: Are child types fixed?

Comment: It's unclear to me how you intend to declare the virtual function. You know a function template cannot be virtual, yet you still want polymorphism?

Comment: The whole idea behind polymorphism is you declare an *interface*, and then the derived classes implement that so you don't have to care about what function gets called.  This kind of sounds like an XY-Problem.  What are you trying to solve with this?

Comment: How are people supposed to know what function to call on `a` if they don't know what type `a` is?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of virtual, you might use `std::variant` and using overload as dispatch:

```
class A {};
class B : public A {};

template<class... Types>
void f(A&, Types... buffers) { std::cout << "A" << sizeof...(buffers) << std::endl; }

void f(B&, unsigned char* buff1) { std::cout << "B1\n"; }
void f(B&, unsigned char* buff1, unsigned int* buff2) { std::cout << "B2\n"; }
```

And then

```
std::variant<A, B> vars[] =  {A{}, B{}};

unsigned char buff1[42]{};
unsigned int buff2[42]{};

for (auto& var : vars) {
    std::visit([&](auto& a_or_b) { f(a_or_b, buff1); }, var);
    std::visit([&](auto& a_or_b) { f(a_or_b, buff1, buff2); }, var);
    std::visit([](auto& a_or_b) { f(a_or_b); }, var);
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/YhzoTE6xx)

Answer (score 1):

Since the various `f` functions really share nothing except their name, I've modeled them as actual separate interfaces, which meshes way better with the existing OOP tools that handle objects optionally implementing interfaces (i.e. `dynamic_cast`). `A` and its own `f` template then just hide away the cross-casting and error handling.

```
template <class... Types>
struct HasF {
    virtual void f(Types... buffers) = 0;
};

struct A {
    virtual ~A() = default;

    template <class... Types>
    void f(Types... buffers) {
        auto *const p = dynamic_cast<HasF<Types...>*>(this);

        if(!p) {
            // Error: the dynamic type cannot handle these arguments.
        }
        
        p->f(buffers...);
    }
};

struct B
: A
, HasF<unsigned char *>
, HasF<unsigned char *, unsigned int *> {
    void f(unsigned char* buff2) override { /* ... */ }
    void f(unsigned char* buff1, unsigned int* buff2) override { /* ... */ }
};
```

[See it live on Godbolt.org](https://godbolt.org/z/YfMG7Es6P)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are looking for `std::any`.

```
class A {
public:
template<class... Types>
void f(Types... buffers) { return f_impl(std::tuple(buffers...)); }
private:
virtual void f_impl(std::any arg) = 0;
};

class B : public A {
// Overrides only 2 options of "generic" f
void f_impl(std::any arg) override
{
    if (auto * tup = std::any_cast<std::tuple<unsigned char*>>(&arg)) {
        // single arg case
    } else if (auto * tup = std::any_cast<std::tuple<unsigned char*, unsigned char*>>(&arg)) {
        // two arg case
    } else {
        throw std::runtime_error("unsupported call"); // or whatever
    }
};
```

However your requirements imply a horrible design problem. Someone who is given an `A` can't know what they can do with it without knowing what subclass it actually is, at which point they should have a reference to that type, instead.